# xcodebuild building both iOS and tvOS targets when only tvOS is requested

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, tvos, xcodebuild

I have an Xcode project with 2 targets: one for iOS and one for tvOS. I'm using the following command-line command to build it:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "/Users/xxx/Code/project.xcworkspace" -scheme "tvOS" -configuration Release -sdk appletvos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-abcdef/Build/Products" BUILD_ROOT="/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-abcdef/Build/Products" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"
```

My project has two dependencies pulled in via CocoaPods with the following Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

def common()
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 3.5'
    pod 'JSONModel', '~> 1.8'
end

target 'iOS' do
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    common()
    pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.9'
end

target 'tvOS' do
    platform :tvos, '9.1'
    common()
    pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-tvOS-SDK', '~> 4.2'
end
```

When I build the iOS target, it works fine. In the build directory I see something like the following:

```
Build
  - Intermediates.noindex
  - Products
    - Release-ios
       - project.framework
       - CocoaLumberjack-iOS
       - JSONModel-iOS
       - Pods_project_tvOS.framework
```

When I build the tvOS target, it's generating ***both*** iOS and tvOS versions of dependencies:

```
Build
  - Intermediates.noindex
  - Products
    - Release-appletvos
       - project.framework
       - CocoaLumberjack-iOS
       - CocoaLumberjack-tvOS
       - JSONModel-iOS
       - JSONModel-tvOS
       - Pods_project_tvOS.framework
```

I've been trying to figure out why this is happening, as it's leading to additional issues in our build pipeline downstream. So far I've tried:

- In the Build Settings I noticed that there were "versions" set for various SDKs I wasn't building (e.g. there was a default Apple Watch version, or on the iOS target there was a default tvOS version). I overrode these default versions with blank values for all except the SDK I'm attempting to build
- Under the Project > Info I noticed that CocoaPods had added "Configurations", with four files like "Pods-project-tvOS.release.xcconfig". I tried modifying my xcodebuild command with `-xcconfig "..."` (linking to the proper config file) but this led to a build failure, claiming there was now a cycle in dependencies: `project-tvOS -> CocoaLumberjack-iOS -> project-tvOS`
- I've tried manually setting the `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` to `1,2` or `3` as appropriate
- I've tried setting `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `YES`

As a test I built using Xcode (without using the `xcodebuild` command line tool) and ***this worked just fine***. So there's something wrong with my command. However I can't rely on Xcode to build this project because I need to automatically create a fat binary from a single command - hence I have a shell script calling `xcodebuild` twice then using `lipo` to combine the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8729 which started with Xcode 10.2 which is related to this Apple [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/20490378).

We switched to running our xcodebuild tests with single platform Podfiles.

Another likely workaround is selecting the old Xcode build system.